# Formatting helper_methods for use in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :nicename

  def nicename(name)
    # all entries in the DB are in lower case and need to be formated
    # for dislay in views:
    name.gsub(/[\s]/,'-').split("-").map {|m|m.capitalize}.join('-')
  end
end
```

In my view I invoke the method nicename like so:

```
<% l.authors.each do |m| %>
    <%= nicename(m.firstname) %>
```

How should I write the method so I can do this in the view:

```
    <%= m.firstname.nicename %>
```

Comment: What if it will look like this `<%= m.nicename %>` ? Will it resolve what you need ?

Comment: No, that wouldn't resolve the problem as authors has firstname, givenname, profession and others. I need to call `nicename` only on `firstname` and `givenname`

Comment: You need to write in that way. You can't write  `m.firstname.nicename` in this way if you want to perform `gsub` on name field. You need pass `name` as parameter

Comment: @thiebo could I know why exactly `m.firstname.nicename` in this format and not let say in `m.nicefirstname` or `m.nicegivenname` ?

Comment: @arm2pro: authors has firstname, givenname, profession and others. I need to call nicename only on firstname and givenname and I don't want to merge for reason of readibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it as you want, without passing an argument, would require extension on the `String` class. That's assuming you are always calling method on strings. Judging from your code it holds true. Here is an example for you:

`lib/core_ext/string.rb`

```
class String
  def nicename
    # all entries in the DB are in lower case and need to be formated
    # for dislay in views:
    self.gsub(/[\s]/,'-').split("-").map {|m|m.capitalize}.join('-')
  end
end
```

Make sure to reload your server and check that class is loaded. Hope it fit your needs.

Comment: Additional comment for the sake of completeness: unicode_utils doesn't have a method `capitalize` so this will not work for accented upper case letters. Use `titlecase` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Monkey patching `String` is *not the only* way. Adding methods to a core class like `String` is a slippery slope. You may decide one day that you want Books to have a nicename too, only with some different formatting for presentation.

You could wrap the object in a presenter class for use in the view, something like:

```
class AuthorController
  def show
    @author = AuthorPresenter.new(author_from_params)
  end
end

class AuthorPresenter
  def initialize(author)
    @author = author
  end

  def firstname
    nice(@author.firstname)
  end

  def nice(name)
    name.gsub ...
  end
end
```

Then in your view, you would use the `@author`

```
@author.firstname
```

This way you keep the presentation logic out of your model, and don't have to globally add methods to `String`.

Of course, if you *really* want to use `author.firstname.nicename` you could wrap the `AuthorPresenter#firstname` in a presenter:

```
class AuthorPresenter
  def initialize(author)
    @author = author
  end

  def firstname
    NamePresenter.new(@author.firstname)
  end
end

class NamePresenter
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def nicename
    @name.gsub ...
  end
end
```

Comment: downvote because your solution doesn't give <%= m.firstname.nicename %>

Comment: If it model related then logic should be moved to model side. Otherwise extending string solution is the more less preferable as suggested Mikhail Nikalyukin.

Comment: arm2pro I've updated my answer to show using presenters to achieve the requested API.